# Check for duplicates in a database and delete them

Tags: mysql, database, duplicates

I have a table structured as follows:

```
table(A, B)
```

They are both primary keys and they are needed to connect two entries in another table (i.e. they simbolize a friendship between users).

**I need to check the table and, if (A,B) exists, delete an eventual (B,A) (or vice-versa).**
Since the database is huge, I can't do this manually for every single entry each time.

Of course, I programmed the script that populated the database to check for this situation and avoid it, but we've been using that script on 8 different PCs and so the different dumps may have "reverse duplicates".

Comment: Do you want to clean-up an existing database table or prevent this in future? Surely a trigger on insert/update could quickly validate if the reverse record is present? In which case you simply need to run a one-off exercise of cleaning up existing data (that doesn't have to run all that quickly)

Comment: Couldn't you declare keys both ways?  As in, UNIQUE(a, b) and UNIQUE(b, a)?  Then the database itself would enforce your constraints without even needing triggers.

Comment: I know its too late now, but this problem could had been avoided by the application: A and B are usually ids and your app should only save pairs into the the table where A < B.

Comment: @John Pickup: I need to clean it up. As stated, I already used a trigger, but we ran the script on different PCs and it may have led to duplicates.

Comment: @Robert: I like your thinking.

Comment: How big is "huge"? It would be easy to sanitise the data, e.g. using Roberts suggestion select * from table where A<B into a temp table, blow away all the data and then copy back. How long can that take? (actually that wouldn't quite work you'd also need to select B,A from table where B<A into your temp table)

Comment: @Robert: That's not possible. Due to the nature of the data we collected, it's possible to have (A,B), but not (B,A) in the database. Still, I need this relationship to be "unique".

Comment: @John Pickup: They are not numerical IDs, they are VARCHARs. You think that would still work? Huge as in (for this table) more than 5 million entries.

Comment: So how do you know which is correct out of (x,y) and (y,x)? If neither is more 'correct' than the other then a cleanup as per above should work fine and in fairly reasonable time.

Comment: It doesn't matter, I just need one of those records. Either one will do.

Comment: @John Pickup: I didn't understand how would I clean it up, sorry. Could you explain it again?

Comment: Looking for a reverse record in the trigger is not very efficient - you only need to check if A>B, and if not swap them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has arisen because the relationship you are trying to describe is symmetrical - but the schema models an asymmetric association. The right to model the problem would be to maintain a table of relationships - then have a table linking users to relationships, e.g.

```
relationship:
   id auto_increment

related:
   r_id foreign key references relationship.id
   u_id foreign key references user.id
   primary key (r_id, u_id)
```

But to clean up the existing data...an obvious approach would be...

```
DELETE FROM yourtable d
WHERE A>B AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM yourtable r
    WHERE r.A=d.B
    AND r.B =d.A
)
```

However, if I recall correctly MySQL doesn't like using a subselect in a delete which references the same table as the delete. So....

```
SELECT d.A,d.B 
INTO dups
FROM yourtable d, yourtable r
WHERE d.A>d.B
AND r.A=d.B
AND r.B =d.A;
```

then....

```
DELETE FROM yourtable
WHERE EXISTS (
 SELECT 1 FROM dups
 WHERE dups.A=yourtable.A
 AND dups.B=yourtable.B
)
```

Not sure if the pushed predicate will still cause a problem, so if that doesn't work....

```
DELETE FROM yourtable
WHERE CONCAT(A, '/', B) IN (
 SELECT CONCAT(A, '/' B) FROM dups
)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Just a note: the correct sintax is INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM. Thanks!